# I am getting src(unknown) when calling an ImageField (pic) on a ForeignKey (handheld) DJANGO

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jinja2

I hope someone can help me out (newbie). I am getting src(unknown) when calling an ImageField (pic) on a ForeignKey (handheld)

I see that I am able retrieve all the other values but not the models.ImageField via "cpu.handheld.pic.url", no errors in the python log. If I user for example "cpu.handheld.reg"_date works as you can see below:

HTML/JINJA:

```
<!-- Listing 1 -->
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
         <div class="card listing-preview">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ cpu.handheld.reg_date }}" alt="">
           <div class="card-img-overlay">
             <h2>
```

python log:

```
[12/Sep/2020 21:51:35] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 61
Not Found: /cpus/Sept. 12, 2020, 8:25 p.m.
**[12/Sep/2020 21:51:35] "GET /cpus/Sept.%2012,%202020,%208:25%20p.m. HTTP/1.1" 404 3474**
```

When using "cpu.handheld.pic.url"

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[12/Sep/2020 21:57:02] "GET /cpus/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8329
[12/Sep/2020 21:57:02] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 61
```

[image]

These are the two models:

=======CPU

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from batt_serials.models import Battery
from serials.models import Serial
from sites.models import Site
from status.models import Status


class Cpu(models.Model):
   cpu = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   **handheld = models.ForeignKey(Serial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)**
   battery = models.ForeignKey(Battery, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.cpu
```

==================SERIAL

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from devices.models import Device

class Serial(models.Model):
   serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   replaced = models.TextField(blank=True)
   old_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.serial_number
```

===================Device

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Device(models.Model):
   make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
   support = models.TextField(blank=True)
   reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.model
```

Option 1: I was thing that I could reference the ForeignKey directly - something like a view for a database table.

Option 2: copy the image path value (pic) "somehow" automatically when selecting the [Device] in the [Cpu] table

Comment: In your model you put that handheld is related to the Serial model

Answer (score 0):

> you have called the DatetimeField. should call ImageField pic

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ cpu.handheld.pic.url }}" alt="">
```

> like this. if share views.py part it can be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I have to answer like this for now:

Your image source, as written in your image tag, references a field that is a DateTime field. Surely that isn't what you intend?

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ cpu.handheld.reg_date }}" alt="">
```

Cpu has a FK to Serial (a model that you haven't shown us in your post), which I assume has a reg-date field like your other Classes, which is likely therefore a DateTime field, not an image url.

Surely you want to reference the 'pic' field on one of your Classes (again, Serializer isn't shown here, so I don't know if it has a pic field; but your Device class does have 'pic').

Notably, your Cpu class and Device class are not connected by any FKs (or anything else), so if it's the device 'pic' field you want to display, you're going to need to rewrite your Models appropriately, and create a relation between Cpu and Device.

Comment: Thanks, I added the third model and after a good nights sleep I see where I messed up. Solution: cpu.handheld.device.pic.url

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I missed a level when trying to reach [pic]. I was getting unknown because there was no [pic] in the"Serial" model.

I added also the third model so the this my help some else and complete the question.

I needed to reach the "Device" model.

Cpu -> Serial -> Device[pic] so the solution is cpu.handheld.device.pic.url

p.s. Since both models have reg_date I tricked myself in think I was in the right model! :-/. I'll try and keep unique fields in the future even though some models are very similar.

Thank you m.arthur for you detailed reply!

Ciao!